# Meteor Collection Conditional Find

Tags: mongodb

I have the following return statement in my Meteor app (dayAgo is defined before this as one day ago):
`return Posts.find({date: {$gt : dayAgo}, status : "approved"})`

However, I need to bypass the `date: {$gt : dayAgo}` filter for elements in the collection that have the following field `pinned : true`. Basically if the post has `pinned : true` I want to return it regardless of it's `date` field. How can I do this?

Comment: Try `{$or: [{pinned: true}, {date: {$gt : dayAgo}}]}`?

Answer (score 0):

```
return Posts.find({$or: [{pinned: true}, {date: {$gt : dayAgo}}], status : "approved"})
```

As per the above query, if pinned is true, date clause will not be evaluated. However, `status:"approved"` will be evaluated for all.